# How to solve this implicit equation involving integral

Tags: calculus, integration, self-learning

Consider the following equation with respect to $\alpha$ defined through a probability density function $f(x) = \exp[x-\exp(x)]$.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-2) e^{\alpha(x-2)}e^{x-e^x}dx = 0.
$$

How to solve this equation, please? Moreover, can we find a closed form for the integral in the first place? If so, then it will be easier to solve for $\alpha$ I suppose. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** By the change of variable $u=e^x$ you get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (x-2) e^{\alpha(x-2)}e^{x-e^x}dx &= e^{-2\alpha}\int_{0}^{+\infty} (\ln u-2) u^{\alpha}e^{-u}du\\\\
&=e^{-2\alpha}\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} \ln u \:u^{\alpha}e^{-u}du-2\int_{0}^{+\infty} u^{\alpha}e^{-u}du\right)\\\\
&=e^{-2\alpha}(\Gamma'(\alpha+1)-2\:\Gamma(\alpha+1)).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: With your formula, I suppose that I need to use some numerical thing to actually solve for $\alpha$. Right? Is there such function in Python or R for the derivative of Gamma function, please?

Comment: @20824 Yes, you have to try a numerical evaluation of your solution. Here we are looking for a solution of $$\psi(\alpha+1)=2 $$ with $\psi$ being the digamma function.

Comment: @20824 Using Wolfram Alpha, a positive solution of $\psi(\alpha+1)=2$ is obtain for $\alpha $ near $6.88342863118604...$

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively, in R there is build-in digamma function and then one can use uniroot to solve for $\alpha$. I got the same answer.